# Markdown renderer understanding footnotes and emoji

Tags: pdf, markdown

I have a Markdown document containing Unicode emojis and footnotes. I want to create a PDF out of it, but I can't find a solution that supports both.

I'm looking for:

- free software (preferably free as in speech, but free as in beer will also do)
- command line, desktop or web service

The output doesn't necessarily have to be pretty. Any other format that can be easily converted to PDF will do as well (HTML etc.)

Answer (score 1):

markdown-it does the trick. The easiest way for one time users is going to:

https://markdown-it.github.io/#fn1

pasting the markdown on the left side and copying HTML from the right side. This can be further processed with your browser or `wkhtmltopdf` to generate a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

[Pandoc](https://pandoc.org) can do this, but one has to enable the emoji extension. The default PDF engine used by pandoc is *pdflatex*, which, as far as I know, doesn't support emojis. (Getting emojis to work in LaTeX is a pain in general.) The best way is hence to use wkhtmltopdf, weasyprint or the like.

This is how the command should look like:

```
pandoc --from=markdown+emoji --pdf-engine=wkhtmltopdf --output=out.pdf input.md
```